# Выбор эллектива

Tags: objective-c, .net, java

В университете появились эллективы JavaEE, MS prog(.NET), Apple (ObjectiveC).
Можно выбрать только один из них. Что посоветуете?

Comment: как же этот вопрос подходит под категорию "Слишком спорно"...здесь нельзя дать однозначного ответа! кто на чём программирует, то и посоветуют, приведут аргументы и они скорее всего будут объективны, для задач решаемых тем или иным языком. Единсвенный вариант - это монструозный ответ описывающий достоинства и недостатки всех перечисленных технологий.

Comment: если нече не шаришь. не шарпа. не джавы. не плюсов - идти на то. что победит в голосовании =)

Comment: @Gorets, учитывая местную аудиторию, победит PHP

Comment: или джава как андроид =)

Comment: А шо це такэ "эллектив"?

Comment: @Barmaley, видимо так нынче называются факультативы

Comment: Узнаем соотношение джавистов и дотнетчиков на Хэшкоде )

Comment: Слово _элективный_ [пишется с одной буквой "л"](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=%FD%EB%E5%EA%F2%E8%E2%ED%FB%E9). @Viacheskav, это на факультатив, это то, что раньше называлось спецкурсом по выбору (elective - избирательный). Факультативом вы можете взять дисциплину дополнительно по желанию, электив обязаны выбрать из нескольких альтернатив.

Comment: Таким образом надо выбрать русский язык. @northerner, 2. *сущ; амер.* факультативный курс (не связанный с основной специализацией студента)

Comment: @karmadro4, русский язык - всегда хорошо.

Насчет связи с специализацией толковый словарь БСЭ не согласен:

> факультатив (франц. facultatif, от лат. facultas - возможность) - необязательный учебный курс или предмет, изучаемый студентами вузов и учащимися средних учебных заведений по их желанию для углубления и расширения научно-теоретических знаний.

Той же трактовки придерживаются классические учебники по педагогике (Подласый, Пидкасистый).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaEE

**HOLYWAR GO ON**

Comment: холивар говорите...обоснуйте, почему Java?=)

Comment: Согласен. Лучше всего ява.  
1. Кроссплатформенность  
2. Гибкость  
3. Обилие готовых библиотек для любых целей  
4. Заодно легко будет обучиться на весьма перспективный в наши дни мобильный рынок (Android).
.NET только-только обещает появиться на WM, что как бы говорит о его кроссплатформенности  
Ifon сейчас популярен разве что среди гиков, да и те уже ждут с придыханием HTC Edge, который будет на Android, так что возможно Apple потеряет небольшую часть поклонников.

Comment: холивар говорите....NET
1. Windows десктопы, фоны, планшеты, Mono(и [Andriod](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143147/) тоже), да что скрывать и web
2. не менее гибкий, но более быстро развивающийся
3. тоже много чего написано один Telerik чего стоит

Comment: в Java нет струкур, а иногда они ох как нужны, тоже за .NET

Comment: учитывая как Oracle забивает на Java, я бы тоже порекомендовал .NET (хотя сам пишу на Java)

Comment: @Spectre, и много вы софта видели написанного на дотнете под android?
Про web не понял, как раз j2ee кажется предпочтительнее выглядит

@Merlin Про структуры согласен

@Viacheslav Oracle забивает на Java?? По-моему java8 значительно улучшится, поэтому не говорил бы так категорично

Comment: @rasmisha, учитывая, что новости приведённой мной неделя от силы, то вы правы, немного софта написано, ИМХО ASP.NET мощная платформа, не знаю почему её недооценивают

Comment: @Spectre Какой новости неделя? Mono для android давно уже есть
Просто теперь они могут VM свою запускать (то есть Dalvik'a в цепи не будет), честно сомневаюсь я что далеко пойдет. Хотя кто знает

Answer (score 6):

Я бы рекомендовал Java. Попробую обосновать. Поскольку речь идет об обучении, но не о зарабатывании бабок, то упор надо сделать на понятность, прозрачность и красоту. Java всем этим требованиям удовлетворяет.

Шарпенский при всем моем пиетете к dot NET вызывает только скукоту. Не зря называют C# - как Visual Basic с фигурными скобками - по сути это так и есть.

Objective C - как язык вроде хорош, но в интерпретации Жобса это жесть. Ну вот как вам такой кусок? Разве такое можно читать без содрогания?

```
-(void)resetClicked:(id)sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reset" message:@"Are you sure you want to reset this puzzle?\nAll of your work will be lost!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

С младых ногтей приучать к такому нельзя!

**Update**

Решил дописать к критике C#. Конечно, в шарпе есть хорошие вещи про которые здесь уже писали оппоненты, но главное мы все таки здесь обсуждаем прозрачность и понятность языка (говоря проще красоту). Так вот шарпе есть несколько вещей которые сильно ухудшают понимание и структуру исходников. Пойду по порядку:

1. Понятие `namespace` - вроде мысль то хорошая, но классы в пределах одного `namespace`, могут быть разбросаны в нескольких файлах. В Java - это пакет, который сосредоточен в пределах одной директории - в Java найти все что относится к пакету не составляет никакого труда. Все логично в противовес шарпу
2. Понятие `virtual/override` - в шарпе виртуальны только методы декларированные как `virtual` и то при условии, что они будут перегружены в наследниках с ключевым словом `override`. В Java все методы виртуальные. Просто? Очень.
3. Понятие `partial` в шарпе - это вообще жесть. Определение класса и даже метода может быть разбросано в нескольких частях исходников. Конечно, если хреново спроектировал, то пихай `partial` - где попадя и потом после тебя - ищи свищи! В Java это невозможно - все определения класса сконцентрированы в одном месте.

Согласен в одном, в том, что опытному прогеру C# дает гораздо больше возможностей (слишком много), за которые приходится платить ухудшением читабельности кода и ухудшением возможностей по коллективной разработке. А программирование коллективный труд, так что такая свобода, считаю, является избыточной!

Comment: С# вызывает скукоту? Visual Basic с фигурными скобками? что за стереотипы? Чем же он непонятнее jav`ы? тем что имеет человеческие properties`ы, функции высшего порядка и лямбда синтаксис для более удобного использования, события, LINQ если уж на то пошло?

толсто, однако.

Comment: Если вы хотели показать, что Obj-C код без переносов - это бяка, то да, я с вами согласен.  
> Objective C - как язык вроде хорош, но в интерпретации Жобса это жесть 
А вы видели Obj-C *до того, как им занялись в Apple*?

Comment: @Barmaley насчет того что C# скучный, это какой то детский лепет, а не аргумент. Вы мне напомнили Дениса Попова, которому не нравится Windows потому, что там [обои скучные][1].

  [1]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUc6QGREUIY&feature=player_detailpage#t=117s

Comment: @Spectre по поводу человеческих свойств  не согласен (выглядят как поля, на самом же деле методы)
Лямбда и у джавистов скоро будет
А всякий сахар лишь убивает понимание "как это работает" (что для изучения мне кажется не так хорошо, хотя в работе, конечно, удобно[но все же лучше знать принципы работы].)

Comment: @rasmisha, ок:

чем же 

    obj.setVapue(obj.getValue()+n);

лучше чем

    obj.Value+=n;

полноценные свойства с геттерами и сеттерами - одно из основных признаков красоты языка, не говоря уже об удобстве использования и читабельности

Comment: Тем что в итоге то делается точно то же самое
А студенты, конечно не все, этого не понимают
Делегат то ручками своими написать не могут уже

Comment: >Тем что в итоге то делается точно то же самое

что-то когда вы пользуетесь услугами Garbage Collector`а, у вас мыслей о ручном управлении памяти не возникает. Почему бы, если вы пользуюсь высокоуровневым языком, не возложить некоторые рутинные вещи на сам язык

Comment: @rasmisha поводу того что "убивает понимание", так это от человека зависит. Никто не запрещает все ручками писать, есть свобода выбора.

Comment: @Spectre я с этим и не спорю. Тоже полезные знания как работает GC. Во время обучения есть время разбираться в этом.

По мне, кстати, джавовский вариант гет/сет ближе

Кстати, Рихтер в книге о CLR писал, что плохая идея свойств в шарпе. И был бы рад, если бы их убрали.

И я, кстати, не говорю, что java великолепна. Просто мне ее в какой-то степени консерватизм нравится.

Comment: вот и вернулись к моему самому первому комментарию о субъективности восприятия языков.

Comment: От C# отталкивает M$. Инстинктивно ждешь какой-нибудь подлянки от них.

Comment: Я просто оставлю здесь кусочек одной копипасты про Java.

- где замыкания?
- где лямбды?
- где свойства?
- где шаблоны?
- где partial-классы?
- где аналог linq и в частности удобные мапперы?
- где расширения методов класса?
- где скрытая имплементация интерфейсов?
- где перегрузка параметров функций?
- где нормальное потребление памяти приложением?
- где пользовательские value types?
- где методы у инстансов primitive types?
- где var и анонимные типы
- где перегрузка операторов?
- где оптимизиции хвостовых вызовов?

Comment: @drdaemon - половина из того что написано есть в Java, вторая половина вредна: в частности перегрузка операторов, partial классы, var и проч. это зло! Из всего перечисленного я бы наверное взял бы в Java только лямбды и linq

Comment: @drdaeman спорно спорно.
Начал писать на каждый пункт, но однотипные ответы. Согласен с @Barmaley половину зло (var, перегрузка операторов, методы у примитивных типов и не только)

Что-то грядет в java8 (clojure и лямбда например)

Что есть шаблоны? чего-то я не понял.

Comment: @rasmisha шаблоны==templates==generics

Comment: Хех, а я как раз на днях [символы с помощью параметризованного типа считал](http://hashcode.ru/questions/110481/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-string-integer-e/110688)...

Answer (score 4):

Тут нужно Вам решить, что Вы хотите от жизни и от будущей работы. Если более интересны серверные и сетевые решения, системные программы, то лучше заняться джавой, если десктопные гуйные приложения, то шарп. Насчет Objective-C, я бы не стал сейчас с ним связываться в качестве объекта изучения в универе.

Еще можно взять книжки по этим языкам и немного из полистать. Что больше понравится, тем и заниматься.

Comment: может я один такой, но большенство вакансий .NET Devoloper, что я встречал, - это ASP.NET

Comment: Я специально не смотрел эти вакансии, но краем глаза периодически таковые попадаются, и притом вакансии именно десктоповых разработчиков.

Answer (score 4):

C#, .NET, Mono

**continue a holy war...**

Почитайте интересную статью на эту тему [Сравнение ОО языков C#, Java](http://zei.narod.ru/Comparison_C__Java_Cpp_3.pdf) и C++.

**UPD**

Ответ [[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley) насчет критики C#

1. Проблем с поиском нужного класса не обнаружил. В C# найти все, что относится к проекту, не составляет никакого труда.
2. "По умолчанию все методы в Java являются виртуальными. Причем, в отличие от C++ и C#, Java от Sun не пытается вычислить, что метод можно вызывать без виртуальной таблицы. Это приводит к замедлению работы. Методы, помеченные как final, становятся не виртуальными. ... К сожалению (несмотря на вкусы), final приводит к некоторым нежелательным последствиям." [источник](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/devtools/perftest.xml).
3. Ключевые слова "может быть", если Вы пишите один, то в общем то можете и не использовать эту функцию. Обычно это используется в довольно больших проектах где несколько человек могут редактировать один и тот же класс. По мне так мегаполезная фича. [Что такое partial класс и какие его преимущества?](http://www.quizful.net/interview/csharp/partial-classes)

Comment: @Barmaley, лимит комментов заставляет писать здесь, но описанная вами "критика", новичку не встретится.

да и вообще о какой прозрачности может идти речь, если даже такой простеший код возвращает неочевидные результаты:

    string a = "wasd";
    string b = "wasd";
    bool c = a == b;

Comment: И что же здесь неочевидно ? 

Просто смотрим а и b указывают на разные объекты или нет.

Comment: В шарпе то выдает очевидный результат лишь из-за перегрузки ==

Comment: банально, но как часто вы сравниваете ссылки на строки и их содержания? странно или не странно, но намного удобнее

Comment: @Spectre ну дак это же странно так сравнивать (объекты в смысле) Вам не кажется? Я никогда так не сравнивал и даже вряд ли буду

Comment: @Barmaley, иногда перегрузка таких операторов как `[]` и `+=` крайне удобна и к тому же интуитивно понятна. во-вторых `var` - далеко не зло, т.к. по идее тип всегда должен вычисляться, а не определяться зарание, наподобие того как сделано в F#

Comment: > по идее тип всегда должен вычисляться, а не определяться зарание

Ностальгируете по вариантной жути? О_о

Answer (score 1):

Objective C. Весьма перспективное направление iOS, где понадобится знание objective-c. C учетом того, что маки и девайсы стоят не дешево, то есть резон выбрать этот курс, чтобы ознакомиться. Все остальное возможно выучить самостоятельно без существенных денежных вливаний.
Все ИМХО.

Comment: Так и толку, что они стоят недешево? Рано или поздно они перестанут позиционироваться как топовые устройства, потому что их будут переплевывать другие аппараты. На одном только лейбле Apple долго не протянет.  
Наоборот, мне кажется, это бесперспективно.

Comment: @ReinRaus, статистика продаж iOS-приложений не согласна с вашей точкой зрения.

Comment: @violet Статистика показывает, что все может измениться в одну секунду.

Comment: @ReinRaus, не знаю как вы, а я с 2008 года слежу за динамикой развития платформы iOS, и как-то она не шибко собирается в одну секунду становится неконкурентноспособной.

Comment: Мобильное направление очень и очень перспективно. Крупные игроки на этом рынке - iOS  и Android. Смешно читать, что Apple в данном сегменте бесперспективно.  
Под десктопные маки - да, не перспективно, под мобильные устройства - очень даже перспективно.

Comment: > C учетом того, что маки и девайсы стоят не дешево, то есть резон выбрать этот курс

С такой логикой надо вспомнить, что Аппле переключились на гламурные консумерские гаджеты... и выбрать продукцию Sun :-)

Answer (score 1):

Если автор преследует цели зарабатывания бабла, то с коммерческой точки зрения конечно же более выгодны технологии JEE и .NET. Причем за JEE платят слегка выше в силу многовендорости (при равной квалификации эта "слегка" - оказывается даже в пределах погрешности). Как язык C# богаче, чем Java. Но красота Java заключается как раз в ее простоте.
Однако после окончания учебного заведения у вас будет еще вся жизнь впереди, чтобы познакомиться с обоими технологиями ближе.
Objective-C за пределами Apple применяется мало, и выиграть по деньгам количественно слабо представляется. Однако нужно отметить что и таких специалистов меньше, чем явистов или дотнетчиков. Это однозначно. И тот факт, что вы с ним сталкивались - лишний плюс в вашу копилку.
Но даже несмотря на все вышесказанное...
пока вы учитесь, я бы рекомендовал бы "натаскать" себя на С/C++. Поскольку С-подобные языки являются своего рода "эсперанто" в мире ИТ. Как правило порог вхождения этих языков несколько выше, чем языков с автоматическим управлением памяти.
Т.е. оседлав C-подобный язык (возможно больше вы с ним и не встретитесь в работе), вы без проблем выучите и JEE/.NET при необходимости. Совсем не нужно упираться в технологии раньше времени.

Answer (score 0):

[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley) (дальше не дает комментировать в Вашу ветку) Тогда вообще не понял, в Java их теперь нет?